# Where is the conversation between Mother and Partner in Episode 2 - Mortimer’s study?

Tags: the-council

When after investigating the Mortimer’s study in Episode 2, at the summary of the quest I got the following screen:

[image: Quest summary]

The thing is, I'm pretty sure I made everything in this quest:

- get disk on the ground;
- read burnt parchment at the fireplace;
- retrieve the key;
- Romans Chapter 11 Verse 11 of the bible -> something special hidden behind the youngest apostle;
- Hebrews Chapter 6 Verse 8 -> another message from Sarah;
- Revelations Chapter 12 Verse 14 -> another hidden message;
- Gospels and Acts of the Apostles under Acts of the Apostles, Chapter 10 Verse 8 will find the final clue;
- Pick lock a small chest on the fireplace.

... and finally...

> Decipher the Nightmare (literal -> object -> pass the check)

So... I still got the "Could have found the conversation between mother and partner" message.

How do I succeed that task?